# Prove that removing $2 K_3$s from $K_5$ leaves a $C_4$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that we have the complete graph $K_5$ and we remove two triangles. I see that we always get a cycle of length $4$ but I am not sure how to prove this.

If we remove one $K_3$ then for the second $K_3$ we have to use at least one of the vertices of the first one, since we only have $5$ in total. So this vertex has degree $2$ already in the decomposition... I don't know where to go from here.

When I say "remove" I mean disregard the edges that the triangles use.

Comment: You know that there are $4$ edges. Can you prove that no vertex has degree at least three? When you remove a triangle, how does this affect the degrees of the vertices of that triangle?

Comment: @JalexStark Every vertex belongs to at least one of those triangles since we have $2$ triangles so $6$ vertices, but we only have $5$ and so each of them is in at least one. No vertex has degree at least $3$ because they belong to these triangles, where they can have degree at most $2$, while one can have degree $4$.

Comment: Suppose one vertex still has degree $4$. What can we say about the removed triangles? (Hint: are the triangles allowed to share an edge?)

Comment: @JalexStark This cannot happen because we have a $K_5$, so it would mean that this vertex does not belong to the triangles?

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you believe you can prove that every vertex has degree at most $2$. Can there be vertices of degree $1$?

Comment: @JalexStark no since each vertex belonged to one of the triangles.

Comment: Now you believe that every vertex has degree $2$, and that there are $4$ edges. Are there any graphs besides $C_4$ with these properties?

Comment: @JalexStark $4$ vertices of degree $2$ and $4$ edges in the left-over graph cannot be anything else than a $C_4$, is this correct?

Comment: You seem to be using the phrase "remove two triangles" to mean that you remove just the edges, not the vertices, of those triangles, except that, if all the edges incident to a vertex have been removed then that vertex gets removed also. It would be good to  make that convention explicit. (Without the "except ..." clause, you'd end up with the disjoint union of $C_4$ and an isolated vertex.)

Comment: Well, the important thing is that we form some sort of decomposition of edges so I thought it is obvious. Thank you for the note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we remove a triangle, the degree of each vertex involved decreases by $2$. So all degrees are even. Furthermore, the two triangles may not share en edge. So every vertex is involved in some triangle. Therefore, there are no vertices of degree $4$.

Putting this together, the final graph has all vertices of degree $0$ or $2$. Therefore, it is a disjoint union of cycles. The final graph has $4$ edges, so it must be a single $4$-cycle. (The smallest disjoint union of two nonempty cycles has $6$ edges.)

Comment: Perfect. You helped me step by step and I appreciate it! Thank you